# What is time complexity of Array.prototype.reduce and overall time complexity of following code

Tags: javascript, time-complexity

What is the time complexity of this program?  I'm mostly concerned about the slice, splice, and reduce method within the for loop and how it impacts the overall performance of this code.

```
function add(array) {
    var newArray = [];

    for (var i =0; i < array.length; i++) {

        var newArr = array.slice();
        newArr.splice(i,1);

        newArray.push(newArr.reduce(function(a,b) {
            return a * b;
        }))
    }

    return newArray;


}
```

Comment: `.reduce()` is *O(n)* in the length of the array; it's just a linear pass. The overall function is the square of the length of the original array.

Comment: Note also that `.slice()` is also *O(n)*. Overall that code does a lot of redundant work.

Comment: Much better (running in linear time) would be `const product = array.reduce((a, b) => a*b, 1); return array.map(x => product/x);`